# Our hot question

Tags: discussion

[The question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/5913/if-i-gain-then-someone-else-loses-correct) is pretty broad and vague, and many answers to that question appear unscientific and inaccurate to me. I have protected the question for now.

Please down vote questions that you feel are not up to standards of this site.

I know that the question is attracting a lot of traffic, which in general is not a bad thing. But, judging from the content, it appears to be layman answers to a layman question - which is not something we should encourage here. If you disagree with the protection, down vote me :)

Comment: But then the question is why did YOU bother to answer it if you find it "unscientific" (whatever that means ... ) ?

Answer (score 3):

I agree with protecting it. However, I am not a layman and I don't think the question is neither vague or broad. He basically asked:

> Is $A \Rightarrow B$ correct?

and I answered:

> No, check this counterexample. And here is some more information if
>   you are interested.

Given that we are economists the term person A loses and person A gains is fairly common and I guess most economists would automatically add "in terms of utilities, given some reference point" (like I did). If that was not clear someone should have asked and improved the question.

As this question unfortunately attracted a lot of attention from the outside, we had many answers and comments like:

- I have an example, so it is always correct. QED.
- You have not mentioned that it IS possible that B could follow from A.
- You pretend as if capitalism is a good thing but it is bad!

I don't think this has anything to do with the quality of the question, I think it is a general problem with economic questions: everyone has an opinion about it and if they think they understand the question they will answer. We just have to learn to deal with them (i.e. downvoting, protecting these questions and making them as precise as possible).

*I won't argue that it is not a great question and I would not mind not allowing these kind of simple questions here, but that is a different matter.*

Btw I think your answer is also inaccurate (see my comment) ;-)